# Binding option + arrow keys/backspace on Mac OS while still being able to enter special characters

Tags: key-bindings, osx, cursor, modifier-key

I want to be able to bind ⌥← to move the cursor to the previous word, ⌥→ to the next word, ⌥↓ to scroll down a page etc. in Emacs on Mac OS, as in native text editing controls, but also still be able to enter special characters using the option key. When I bind `mac-option-modifier` or `ns-alternate-modifier` to `'alt`, I can bind things like I want, but no longer enter special characters; when I bind it to `'none`, I can enter special characters but can’t use it for my key bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Emacs supports binding the Mac modifier keys to different internal keys](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Mac-_002f-GNUstep-Customization.html#Mac-_002f-GNUstep-Customization) depending on what kind of key event they’re used to trigger:

> The value of each variable is either a symbol, describing the key for any purpose, or a list of the form (:ordinary symbol :function symbol :mouse symbol), which describes the modifier when used with ordinary keys, function keys (that do not produce a character, such as arrow keys), and mouse clicks.

So you can use this to allow `A-` as the binding prefix for the option key when used in combination with ‘function keys’ (including arrow keys and backspace), but leave it set to `'none` for all other combinations, which enables typing special characters as usual:

```
(setq ns-alternate-modifier '(:ordinary none :function alt :mouse alt))
```

The specific key bindings to emulate native Mac OS text controls are:

```
;; note that scroll-up and scroll-down are reversed in Emacs compared to most apps
(global-set-key (kbd "A-<up>") 'scroll-down-command)
(global-set-key (kbd "A-<down>") 'scroll-up-command)
(global-set-key (kbd "A-<left>") 'backward-word)
(global-set-key (kbd "A-<right>") 'forward-word)
(global-set-key (kbd "A-<backspace>") 'backward-kill-word)

;; the following key bindings emulate the native command key scrolling and text editing shortcuts
(global-set-key (kbd "s-<up>") 'beginning-of-buffer)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-<down>") 'end-of-buffer)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-<left>") 'move-beginning-of-line)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-<right>") 'move-end-of-line)
(global-set-key (kbd "s-<backspace>") (lambda ()
                                        (interactive)
                                        (kill-line 0)))
```